# pandas setting with enlargement fails with a large DataFrame, possible bug

Tags: python, pandas, append

I want to add one row to pandas DataFrame. I figured that I can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=range(10**6-1)))
X.loc[len(X)] = 42
```

However when the length of my DataFrame is `10**6` or anything bigger it seems to fail:

```
Y = pd.DataFrame(dict(y=range(10**6)))
Y.loc[len(Y)] = 42

IndexError: index out of bounds
```

This seems obvious bug to me. I wonder what is so magical in this `10**6` though..

I am running pandas 16.2 on 64bit windows 7 and python 2.7.

E: I couldn't find anything on github about this so I went ahead and created an issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10692

Hopefully that is the right thing to do.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a bug.  Here is the documentation on "setting with enlargement" and this should work for loc or ix (but not iloc). http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#setting-with-enlargement It's new with version 0.13.  I get the same message you are getting and I'm using 0.16.1.  What version are you using?

Comment: I somewhat edited the original question to reflect this situation better.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10692

Comment: The issue seems to have been fixed now.